How do I "update" a type in Typescript?
I have this class:
type Config = {
    magic: string;
};

class ConfigManager {
    private readonly configPath: string;
    private config: Config | null;

    public constructor(configPath: string) {
        this.configPath = configPath;
        this.config = null;
    }

    public loadConfig() {
        try {
            this.config = /* read file and parse json */ ;
            return true;
        } catch {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public getConfig(): Readonly<Config> | null {
        return this.config;
    }
}

Initially, the config is not loaded, so the type is T | null. But after it is loaded, it should be just T. Unfortunately, with the current setup, it doesn't recognize that.
function main() {
    const configManager = new ConfigManager("./run/configs/config.json");
    if (!configManager.loadConfig()) {
        return 1;
    }

    console.log(configManager.getConfig().magic); // Object is possibly null
    return 0;
}

main();

Is it possible to get Typescript to recognize that the config is definitely not null after a successful load?

You could make loadConfig() a type guard method as shown in this playground link. (It's complicated because you've made config private, so I've had to make the class generic so there's some way to name the type we care about.  If config were not private it would be simpler.) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz That looks like what I'm looking for. Your example doesn't quite work for my purposes, but I've managed to hack it up a bit so it does (I'm passing the ConfigManager to another class). An answer that explains how it works would be nice, I did think generics might be the way to go (a library I'm using also uses this trick internally it seems).

You can move the loading of the config to before constructing the ConfigManager, e.g. as a static method.
class ConfigManager {
    private readonly config: Config;

    public constructor(config: Config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public static loadConfig(configPath: string) {
        try {
            return new ConfigManager(/* read file and parse json */);
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public getConfig(): Readonly<Config> {
        return this.config;
    }
}

function main() {
    const configManager = ConfigManager.loadConfig("./run/configs/config.json");
    if (!configManager) {
        return 1;
    }

    console.log(configManager.getConfig().magic);
    return 0;
}


Unfortunately, this loses the purpose of the ConfigManager class, since at that point I might as well use the raw Config object.

@404NameNotFound Yes, that would be even better. Your ConfigManager is a function pretending to be a class

Perhaps that may be in this example, but on my actual project this config manager manages a lot of configs. Plus, it is more convenient to have a central place than to pass objects around.

@404NameNotFound so maybe you want two classes, ConfigLoader and ConfigManager, where ConfigLoader tries to load all your configs, and if it succeeds then it can create a ConfigManager with non-null configs.

t@404NameNotFound What exactly does "managing configs" mean then? What is the goal of the abstraction? If it's lazy-loading the configurations, then probably the public interface just shouldn't distinguish between loadConfig() and getConfig() - expose only one method that always returns a config, never null.

If you want TypeScript to treat the result of configManager.loadConfig() as a way to determine that configManager.getConfig() will return a non-null value, then you need loadConfig() to be a type guard method that returns a type predicate of the form this is XXX for a suitable XXX type.  The specifics of what XXX is will be driven by your use case, but I'll show an example.
If config weren't private, then XXX could be something like {config: Config}. But since it is private, you can't refer to the config property directly.  So instead I'll refactor to use generics:
class ConfigManager<T extends null = null> {
  private readonly configPath: string;
  private config: Config | T;

  public constructor(configPath: string) {
    this.configPath = configPath;
    this.config = null as T;
  }

  public loadConfig(): this is ConfigManager<never> {
    try {
      this.config = /* read file and parse json */ { magic: "abc" };
      return true;
    } catch {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public getConfig(): Readonly<Config> | T {
    return this.config;
  }
}

Here the type parameter T corresponds to "what other than Config could config be holding".  It should start off as null (I've made it default to null), and then when you call loadConfig(), it should be the impossible never type. So when T is null, the type of config is the union Config | null, and when it's never, the type of config is just Config (since never is absorbed by unions).
The loadConfig() method above is a type guard method that returns this is ConfigManager<never>, meaning when you call configManager.loadConfig(), a true result means that configManager should be narrowed to ConfigManager<never>.  Let's try it:
function main() {
  const configManager = new ConfigManager("./run/configs/config.json");
  configManager.getConfig().magic // error
  if (!configManager.loadConfig()) {
    return 1;
  }
  console.log(configManager.getConfig().magic); // okay
  return 0;
}

Looks good. Before you call loadConfig(), the type of configManager.getConfig() can be null, but after you call it and check that it's true, the type of configManager.getConfig() is known not to be null.
Playground link to code

Does the T extends null reflect the initial type being null? E.g., if I wanted the config to be a number before loading an object, it would be T extends number?

Yeah, you could make it T extends number = number if you want. You can play around with it and if you have follow up questions then let me know, or open a new post if they are outside the scope of the question as asked here.
